# Text to Speech with Meteor?

Tags: meteor

Working on a questionnaire app for cognitively challenged users. Various levels of autism, different types of brain injury, different types of brain birth defects.

Got a prototype working with HTML/CSS/Coffeescript/LocalStorage. Real app will be my first venture into full client/server appland.

2 issues. Lots of graphics and text to speech.

We have to assume that our users can't read. Every screen will have one to three images average of 75k. Every bit of text needs to be clickable or hoverable for text to speech.

Our prototype uses a TTS engine called Festvox/Festival.

So, how is Meteor going to be with sending a lot of images? And should I assume that our app would be sending images and data from the node.js side and TTS from our server? Any ideas on how difficult that will be to hook up?

Thanks,

Charlie Magee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For images, these will be handled better in future I think as it states in the code comments however at the moment these can be placed in the public folder. These will be served from the meteor server for now but maybe in the future something else.

As for the TTS it might be easier for now to implement this on another server/virtual server with the meteor server communicating the content needed and then serving it up. Until a TTS package is added to meteor/node then I think this is your only way forward.

Comment: Looks like they are working on a internal http package but for now the http package should be good to communicate over to the other server and get the data back. Some more examples might be easier, what language is the TTS code?

Answer (score 0):

I just found https://github.com/yogiben/meteor-tts and it seems promising. There is currently a hiccup, which I think is related to not having proper API keys, and it also requires an internet connection. Probably not reliable enough for your needs, but I'm going to see if I can solve the API key issue.